# Recursive function to for tree data structure

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, tree

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4hF3.gif) Top value is ID, bottom does not concern you. I need to write a function that receives tree top element(they are called ministries) and goes down the tree and checks if some its children is attached to him itself(or other big ministry). Basically true or false return would be ideal. I just can not make the function because it always returns false at the last return because the first checked child did not point to the ministry. At the end it does return true, but what's the use of that.

And on with the code:
The Element (lot like node in linked list) But single Node has an array of all the children pointers.

```
class Element {
public:
    int id;
    int value;
    bool is_parent;
    bool is_ministry;
    bool is_children;
    int children_count;
    int children_in;
    bool is_visited;
    Element **children; //CHILDREN ARRAY
    Element* next; //TO NOT LOSE ELEMENTS
    Element(int _id,int _value,int _children_count=0,bool _is_ministry=false){
        this->id=_id;
        this->value=_value;
        this->is_ministry=_is_ministry;
        this->children_in=0;
        this->children_count=_children_count;
        this->next=NULL;
        this->is_visited=false;
        this->is_children=false;
        if(_children_count>0){
            this->is_parent=true;
            this->children = new Element*[_children_count];
        }
        else{
            this->is_parent=false;
            this->children=NULL;
        }
    }
    ~Element(){
        ///delete children;
    }
};
```

Main recursion function:

```
    bool error_1_recursive(Element *_parent){
            cout << "Inspecting: (in this example the first to come here is id11) " << _parent->id<< " ";
                if(_parent->is_ministry ) {
                    cout << "Found ministry";
                    return true;
                }
///Did not find ministry, going further down the recursion.
                if(_parent->is_parent){
                    for(int i=0;i<_parent->children_in;i++){
                        error_1_recursive(_parent->children[i]);
                    }
                }
        }
```

I could not make 1 function for it because i need to check if the given object is ministry, because the object I need to pass first is actually a ministry.

```
void error_1_recursive_container(Element *_parent){
                cout << "Receives main child with id " << _parent->id << " ";
                Here it goes trough main child children and recursion can start.
    for(int i=0;i<_parent->children_in;i++){
                    if(error_1_recursive(_parent->children[i])==true){
                        cout << "The main child has atleast 1 child that points to ministry" << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
```

And lastly, a way to go trough the tree.

```
void Going_around(Element *_parent){
        cout << _parent->id << " ";
        if(_parent->is_parent){
            for(int i=0;i<_parent->children_in;i++){
                Going_around(_parent->children[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a return statement at the end of `error_1_recursive`.
You need to use the result of `error_1_recursive` when called in the loop.
If you want to return true, as soon as you get any true result:
`if (`*recursive call*`) return true;`